# AWS EB CLI: How to reset (unset) the default environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I accidentally entered the default environment (using **eb use** ) and looks like it broke everything - all the applications related to this application (stupid AWS terminology) stopped working. I just want to remove this default setting and I don't know how.

Comment: you can terminate configuration or load configuration from EB dashboard

Comment: @harshmanvar yeah I can do (actually what I did) but it takes pretty much time and I just wanted to unset the default environment.

Comment: remove default env and set new...and set whole new application on EB

Answer (score 0):

Use `git diff` to see the changes it made. Use `git status` to see your current branch.

Edit the `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` file and remove the two lines which set the default environment for your branch:

```
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: MyDev-env
  sprint9:
    environment: MyDev-env
```

If you are on branch `sprint9` then remove those last two lines and save.